# UI Sortable moves scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-sortable

I have issue with jQuery sortable.

Here is live example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xjyzjr8/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    a<br>
    b<br>
    c<br>
    d<br>
    e<br>
    f<br>
    g<br>
    h<br>
    i<br>
    j<br>
    k<br>
    l<br>
    m<br>
    n<br>
    o<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.a').sortable();
});
```

CSS:

```
.b {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In this case I have div with scroll. I scroll to the end of the div and I try to sort element using drag&drop. After this action, scroll in div jumps to beginning of this div. How I can "remember" position of scroll and "revert" it after sortable?

Comment: It moves all layer, not only the elements. Are you sure that the fiddle reproduces your problem? If yes, please, add more details or explain better what you need, because it's hard to see.

Comment: actually you need to add one more inner div with scrollbox (with class 'b')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the scroll position and then reapply it when you stop moving the object.

JSFIDDLE: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3xjyzjr8/3/)

```
$(function(){
    var scrollTop = 0;
    $('.a').sortable({
        start: function(event, ui){
          scrollTop = ui.item.scrollTop();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
          ui.item.scrollTop(scrollTop);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `sortable()` method on the inner `<div id="b">` and put every element you want to sort inside a `<div>` tag so they can be treated as DOM elements.
Here's a working solution [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xjyzjr8/4/)
You might want to check [THIS](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) topic.